# Error bars overlap but effect is significant in glmm. What's going on?

Tags: r, lme4

I have run the following glmm:

`mod<-glmer(data=newdata, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + flr_num + (1|individual), family=poisson)`

and get this output from `summary()`

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: total_flr_vis ~ treatment + flr_num + (1 | individual)
Data: newdata

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
706.8    718.9   -349.4    698.8      148 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1461 -0.8155 -0.3522 -0.2022 14.1669 

Random effects:
Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
individual (Intercept) 4.066    2.016   
Number of obs: 152, groups:  individual, 42

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.610176   0.432666  -3.722 0.000198 ***
treatmentR  -0.457492   0.121054  -3.779 0.000157 ***
flr_num      0.037063   0.005064   7.319  2.5e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) trtmnR
  treatmentR -0.117       
  flr_num    -0.416  0.040
```

But I get the following plot for `treatment` using `plot(allEffects(mod))`

[image]

I don't understand why the effects plot shows overlapping error bars while the `summary()` output tells me that the effect of `treatment` is significant. Is there a problem with the model, or is it the plot? How can I troubleshoot this?

Here is the residual plot (which I got using `plot(mod)`)

[image]

I'm not totally sure how to interpret this plot, but it does not look random to me, thus I suspect that there is something wrong with the model.

I am happy to post data if someone can tell me where to do that.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Your first plot doesn't show what you think it shows.

Comment: What does it show then?

Comment: If you need help with statistical model diagnosis, you should probably ask your question at [stats.se], this doesn't seem like a specific programming question.

Comment: Thanks very much. My mind was divided about that. It seems like it may mostly be down to a lack of understanding of what the software is doing when it generates the plots (hence I posted it here), while the larger issue seems more appropriate for CV...